# String containing latitude convertion to plain number

Tags: java, android, string

In order no write a track in IGC format I need to transform the string with latitude `41:33,81581` in something like this `413381581` that is without the markings.

I managed to remove the extra characters but if the the latitude ends with a zero (for example `41:33,8158`) I have one less character in the final string that I have to add.

Is there any straight forward solution (like using String.format()) that I can use or do I have to hammer down a string parser for this?

Comment: A sample of the code you're using wouldn't go amiss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
private String parseString(final String in)
{
    return String.format("%4.5f", Double.parseDouble( in.replace(":", "").replace(',', '.') ) ).replace(",", "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer H9kDroid. I have to tweek a little your solution because I have to format xxx:yy,zzzzz in xxxyyzzzzz
In a while I post my code.

Comment: here it is:
 
`lists = lat.split(":");
 if(lists[0]!=null&&lists[1]!=null)
 lat=String.format("%02d%02.3f",Integer.decode(listas[0]),Double.parseDouble(lists[1].replace(',','.')));
lat = lat.replace(",", "");`